# How to deselect a HTML button tag with a simple chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, focus, blur

I have created a chrome extension with a simple popup.html file that contains a [button tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) as first element inside the body. When I test it on Chrome 26 under OS X, each time I click on my  extension icon that triggers the popup, my button seems selected/focused given that I see it with a blue halo. I cannot figure out how to disable auto focus. It seems autofocus is applied on the first tag from the popup.html file. I tried to apply `blur()` on the button instance retrieved with `document.getElementById` but it does not work.

Is there any solution? workaround? alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I found consists of adding `tabindex="1"` on the `html` tag. I tried to put focus on other elements or to use `autofocus="autofocus"` but this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set focus to element either by js `el.focus()` or by the new html5 `autofocus="autofocus"` attribute
You cannot remove focus from an element unless you set focus on some other element - so you can set focus on some bogus anchor element or something to remove the focus from your button