# Chrome Extension's popup.html automatically scrolls down & focuses on the hyperlink when opened

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a weird issue. Let me describe it as best as I can:

**The Set Up:**

I have a Google Chrome extension opens up a popup.html window when the extension icon is clicked. I use this extension from both MacOS (recent public build) and Windows (Windows 7 - recent build)

**The Problem:**

Most of the extension is just text. However, towards the end of the page, there is a hyperlink. Without showing much details, I have attached a screenshot here (apologize for blocking the text and the features). [image]

Whenever I click on the extension icon, the popup.html window opens up to the location where the hyperlink is on the page (at the bottom). And the hyperlink is focused (as if you have mouse over it - with the link underlined and the element highlighted).

You can see from the screenshot that the ***"Statements from..."*** hyperlink is focused. I have experimented with a simple vanilla page with a single hyperlink - and the page scrolls down to the link and the hyperlink is auto-focused.

I don't have any auto-focus property in my css.

**What I have done to troubleshoot**

- I made my css very simple (just background color and font color).
- I tested with another simple link - have the same result. It's as if tries to find the first URL link on the page and jumps to that location and highlights it.
- Tried it on another computer (PC). More details below.

**More Details**:

I notice this problem ONLY on MacOS (recent Chrome build). I also tested this on Windows 7 with Chrome 55.0.2883.87 -> This issue ***doesn't happen*** there. popup.html opens up normally at the top.

**Question:**

Any suggestions why this problem is happening and how to fix this?

**EDIT - MORE DETAILS**

Below is the **manifest.json** file:

```
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "AppName",
  "short_name": "AppShortName",
  "description": "Extension Description",
  "version": "0.0.0.6",
  "homepage_url": "appURL",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
  "icons": {
        "16": "16.png",
        "48": "48.png",
        "128": "128.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["browser.js", "getTabSource.js", "eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon4.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "TITLE"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "unlimitedStorage"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Popup Title</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

      <script src="browser.js"></script> // Nothing significant is going on here
      <script src="getTabSource.js"></script> //This does backend calls to my backend server and returns the result to popup.js. No UI work is here.
      <script src="popup.js"></script> // All my UI work is here.

      <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='header' id="header">
        <div id="help" title="" type="" icon-help="">?</div>
        <h1 id="banner">TITLE</h1>
        <div><img class="headerImage" src="icons3/Line.png"></div>
        <h3 id="title">subtitle</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="spinner" id="loading"></div>
    <div class="bodyContainer" id="bodyId">content goes here (dynamically generated by DOM in popup.js
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**browser.js**

```
if (typeof browser === 'undefined' && typeof chrome !== 'undefined') {
  window.browser = chrome;
}
```

**popup.js**

```
function getCurrentTabUrl(callback) {
  var queryInfo = {
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  };

  browser.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    var url = tab.url;
    console.assert(typeof url == 'string', 'tab.url should be a string');
    callback(url);
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {    
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').forEach(function (el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            browser.tabs.create({
              url: event.target.getAttribute('href')
            });
        });
    });

    var responseCallBack = function(responseFromServer) {
        var responseText = responseFromServer.response.toLowerCase();

        switch(responseText) {
          case "success":
                processSuccessResponse(responseFromServer);
                break;

          case "error":
                processErrorResponse(responseFromServer);
                break;
        }

    };

    var processSuccessResponse= function(appResponse) {
        // creates the dom elements
        // creates a div element with lots of text
        // adds a link at the bottom 

        var headerContainer = document.createElement("div");
        headerContainer.className = "headerContainer";

        var aHeaderTitle = document.createElement("a");
        aHeaderTitle.className = "aHeaderTitle";
        var aHeaderText = document.createTextNode(appResponse.text);
        aHeaderTitle.appendChild(aHeaderText);

        aHeaderTitle.href = appResponse.link;  // Page scrolls down and jumps to this link

        headerContainer.appendChild(aHeaderTitle); 
        var bodyContainer = document.getElementById("bodyId");
        bodyContainer.appendChild(headerContainer);
        document.body.appendChild(bodyContainer);
    };
});
```

**EDIT - FOUND A SOLUTION**

**I knew I wasn't going crazy!** Apparently, this is a feature on Google Chrome extensions, and not a bug. I did more searching and found this question: [Chrome Extension - first link is auto-focused in popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701082/chrome-extension-first-link-is-auto-focused-in-popup)

From there, the solution is essentially to use tagindex = "-1" on the `a` elements to prevent the extension to auto focus on it during load.

Hope this helps other folks who may have the same issue.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I added more information here.